# Why does the Cholesky decomposition exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition), given any matrix $A$, we can sometimes decompose $A = LU$ using Gaussian elimination. Other times, a permutation matrix is needed, giving $PA = LU$.

If $A$ is Hermitian positive-definite, I can show that IF no permutation matrix is needed, then Gaussian elimination gives $A=LU$ which I can eventually massage and get the Cholesky decomposition $A=LL^*$. However, it seems that Hermitian positive-definite matrices are special in that no permutaiton matrix is ever needed, and hence the Cholesky decomposition always exist. Why?

Comment: It is in Fundamentals of Matrix Computations by David S. Watkins.  It is a beautiful proof, but perhaps a little too much to write down here.

Comment: @Stephen: thanks for the reference. Perhaps a hint or a summary would help? I do not have access to any libraries that would have math books :(

Comment: It uses something called the Schur complement.  I tried using google to find online proofs.  Maybe this would work? http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/schur-comp.pdf

Comment: Oh actually, I think I figured out a proof. Suppose that you are performing elimination and at some stage, the $k^{th}$ pivot came out as zero. Look at the elimination matrix $E$ thus far, and let $x$ be the $k^{th}$ row of $E$. Then $xAx^* = 0$, contradicting the positive-definiteness of $A$

Comment: I don't remember it being that simple.  Also I don't understand your proof.

Comment: For example, why must the $(1,1)$ entry of $A$ be positive? Because we can take $x = (1, 0, ..., 0)$ and observe that $xAx^*$ must be positive.
Now, perform elimination on the first column of $A$, and obtain $A'$. Why must entry $(2,2)$ of $A'$ be positive? Suppose otherwise, and suppose in the elimination step, we subtracted $n$ times row 1 from row 2. Then let $x = (-n, 1, 0, ..., 0)$. Then what is $xAx^*$? Well, $xA$ is the second row of $A'$, which by assumption is $(0,0, stuff)$. So $xAx^*$ is $0$. For subsequent rows, use what I described in the previous comment.

Comment: This is the easy part of the proof.  You write it as a block matrix $\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B^T & C\end{pmatrix}$.  You can show that $A$ is positive definite using the argument you showed.  So you apply Cholesky on the matrix $A$ (the proof is by induction on the size of the matrix).  But then you are left with a matrix $\begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & S\end{pmatrix}$, where $S$ is the Schur complement.  And then you have to show that the Schur complement is positive definite to finish off the proof by induction.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: An additional question: If $A$ is Hermitian positive SEMI-definite, wikipedia says that we can still find $A = LL^*$ although this decomposition is no longer unique, and allowing $L$ to have $0$ on diagonals. Does the proof using Schur complement give a proof for this case too? Mine certainly doesn't

Comment: I don't know the answer to the semi-definite case.

Comment: Silly me, wikipedia itself has the proof ><

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diagonal entries of $U$ in $A=LU$ are quotients of successive main diagonal minors of the matrix $A$. If $A$ is positive definite, the main minors are all positive. Sometimes this is called the Hurwitz criterion.

Put the diagonal elements of $U$ into a diagonal matrix $D$, then $A=LU=LDL^*$. Which again shows that the Cholesky decomposition works, since the critical numbers of the algorithm are these diagonal entries.